# Phased Deployment of serverless environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, serverless

these days we are on the way to move to the serverless world. Our company is a SaaS company that serves customers (tenant) and each customer is an organization. 
Today our server api has a new version each time we publish a new release. This version is assigned per customer (tenant) and our customers can choose when to move to the latest stable version.
In the move to the serverless world we do not see something like that out of the box.
In AWS we saw that there are versioned lambdas but this is not a per tenant solution and more like end users solution. We can build something on that (+ also make a stage in api gateway per version) but is smells like a hack to us

Did we miss something? 
is what we are trying to do is wrong?

Comment: If you are talking about AWS API Gateway, could you use stages?  Create a stage for each version?

Comment: that can be done, but what about lambda called from SQS? CloudWatch?

Comment: Maybe tagging the lambda function with the version that matches the stage? Then call the appropriate version of the lambda function from the matching stage.